# How to find out if one element in array has false value for property and if all elements have true value using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of several objects, they have a `isClosed` bool property. I would like to know how to determine:

1. **if all** values are true
2. **if only one** of these values false

using Linq.

Comment: `All` and `Any` of `Enumerable`?

Comment: @NtFreX Any won't give correct result for **only one** false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can paraphrase your questions like this:

I would like to know how to determine:

1. If count of `false` = 0
2. If count of `false` = 1

You can simply use LINQ `Count`:

```
switch (collection.Count(x => !x.isClosed))
{
    case 0:  
        // case 1, all values are true
        break;

    case 1:
        // case 2, exactly one of these values is false
        break;

    default:
        // other cases, more than 1 false value
        break;
}
```

With this approach you will iterate through your `collection` only once.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item() { IsClosed = true },
            new Item() { IsClosed = true },
            new Item() { IsClosed = true }
        };

var allValuesAreTrue = items.All(it => it.IsClosed);
var onlyOneValueIsTrue = items.Count(it => it.IsClosed) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq .all like

It tells you if all the elements in a collection match a certain condition. It is part of the System.Linq namespace in the .NET Framework. It returns true or false.

```
if (array.All(element => element.isClosed))
            {
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve both your desired requirements using the code below :

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
var myClass1 = new MyClass {IsClosed = true};
var myClass2 = new MyClass { IsClosed = true };
var myClass3 = new MyClass { IsClosed = true };
list.Add(myClass1);
list.Add(myClass2);
list.Add(myClass3);
var response=list.All(x => x.IsClosed);
```

It returns true if all elements of your list have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = arr.Count(a => a.isClosed);
if(count == arr.Length)
    //all
else if(count == 1)
    //only one
else
    //not all, but more than one
```